# search for highest and lowest value, and delete duplicates

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, duplicates, filtering

[image: Exemple]

What I'm looking for is, in Row D i have different repeated values, and i want to keep from each individual value in D, the highest and lowest correspondent value in Row F, and delete the rest of the duplicates.
This is just an example with 2 different "unloading's", I do however have and variable number of them.

Any idea how to solve this?

I didnt try anything, because i have no idea how to even start coding this.
but the goal is that i end up with just 2 values in column F for each individual value in column D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
=query(D2:F,"Select D,min(F),max(F) where D is not null group by D")
```

Comment: This is working perfectly but i noticed an issue, that i cant figure out how to correct.
 sometimes the value in column E, wont match the max value in F.
Example: Columns E has 2 different dates for the same value in D, therefor F may have an inferior value on the later date, and im pulling the max value, instead of the "latest" value date wise.
Is there a way to pull the info we are getting from F matching the max value of E?

Comment: I think you will need to pose this as a new question, as your original question only refers to columns D & F as being relevant. But yes, definitely possible to do what you want.